# Excel VBA Stack Overflow

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, overflow

I have stack overflow problems in"

- Excel 16.60 365 Subscription (Mac)
- MS VBA 7.1 c 2012 (yes *2012*)
- macOS Big Sur 11.6.5

This seems to be a common problem, but I cannot find a solution.

The following snippet works fine when I step through it, but the DateAdd("m", 1, vDate) function fails with "Run-time error 6: Overflow" when I run the code.

Is the DateAdd function in 2012 VBA just broken on Excel 16.60? Is there a workaround?

I need to reliably parse "Fri 15th April @ 9:38am" into a date & time serial number without Overflow.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim vDate As Variant

'   Same overflow problem occurs when creating vDate with either DateSerial or CDate...
'   vDate = DateSerial(2022, 3, 15)
    vDate = CDate("March 3, 2022")
    
    Debug.Print "Orig date = " & vDate
    Debug.Print "New date = " & DateAdd("m", 1, vDate) '<-- Fails w overflow when run.

End Sub
```

Comment: Code works fine for me on a Windows PC. Version _MS VBA 7.1 c 2012 (yes 2012)_ is just normal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `Dim vDate as Variant` to `Dim vDate as Date` ?

That would force it to allocate 8 bytes instead of Variant allocating whatever it thinks it needs for the given value.

Otherwise try replace **DateAdd()** with

```
DateSerial(Year(vdate), Month(vdate) + 1, Day(vdate))
```

Comment: I started off as data type Date. Same problem. I switched to Variant, but that didn't help.

I gave up trying to get VBA to work both step-through and running the code. I switched to a different approach where I parsed the date and time from the imported data into a properly formed string. I then put it into a spreadsheet cell which properly formatted it using a custom format "mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM."

This problem of Excel Mac VBA having stack overflow problems when running code and NOT having overflow problems when stepping through the exact same code has been around since Excel 2011.